# C++ returning queue pointer from function error

Tags: c++

I have a function

```
queue< pair<int,int> > * factorize(int n) {
...}
```

It shows this compile error.

```
generatePrimes.cpp:20: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token
generatePrimes.cpp:20: error: expected `,' or `;' before '<' token
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you don't include necessary header files (`queue` and `utility`), or don't have `using namespace std` or both.

To overcome the first problem include the headers. To overcome the second one either add `using` or provide fully qualified names (`std::queue` and `std::pair`).

Comment: Thanx, I didnt write namespace.